# Icons in Solr Administration User Interface

Tags: user-interface, solr, administration

In the Solr Administration User Interface, selecting "overview". Sometimes in the options "Optimized" and "Current" displays an icon such as "forbidden" instead of the usual "accept". That means that icon? should I care about it?
(Sorry but I have not enough karma to upload images that would help.)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "✓" vs "✖"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Optimized** :

- All existing index segments are merged into one single segment (1 is default but it can be more according to [`maxSegments`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22optimize.22)). Deleted documents are expunged during the merge (deleted docs = marked as deleted, but they still require space until a merge occurs). Note that the commit option `expungeDeletes="true"` also merges all segments with pending deletes.
- The index in its current state is written on storage (hard commit), it occupies less space than a non optimized index because of the merged segments and the expunged docs (like a hard disk defrag).

Optimize operation is very expensive because it involves reading and re-writing the entire index. Segments are usually merged as documents are added according to the Merge Policy, optimize just triggers a [forceMerge](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#forceMerge-int-).

Having a non optimzed index is not necessarilly a bad thing, especially if you have frequent index updates (cf. [Optimization Considerations](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Optimization_Considerations)).

---

**Current** :

No changes have been made on the index since the last commit or soft commit, meaning that all recent operations are visible (e.g. you can search & retrieve the last added documents).

Quoted from [Shawn Heisey's comment](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-Admin-core-status-Index-is-not-quot-Current-quot-td4130493.html#a4130687) on Lucene forum, referring to a *non current* index :

> This basically means that Lucene has detected an index state where 
>   something has made changes to the index, but those changes are not yet
>   visible.  To make them visible and return this status to 'true', do a 
>   commit or soft commit with openSearcher enabled.

(cf. DirectoryReader [isCurrent](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#isCurrent--)).